# Do Jews Support Outlawing the Offending of Prophets?

Tags: navi-prophets, politics-government

There is a petition on the the White House website to ban anything that insults the prophets of any major religion. Here is the content of the Petition: https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/petition/outlaw-offending-prophets-major-religions/94kL1tsN

It clearly enacts prohibition to *all* the prophets of major religions. This petition would  seem to promote interfaith peace and harmony.

Would Jews and Rabbis support this type of thing? Why or why not?

Comment: There is potentially a legitimate question buried in here about interfaith relations, perceptions of "offense", and civil law, but this post is not serving in that capacity so I have closed it.  Please come to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam) to discuss.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Why this post is not serving in that capacity for what it was meant to be posted. Can you justify your action?

Comment: Would you support a petition outlawing insulting different sports teams? Doing so would prevent many people being offended. Don't you want to support harmony?

Comment: I have since edited the question to bring  it more in line with what is on topic for this site.

Comment: The link in the question now leads to a "404 Page Not Found" page.

Answer (score 4):

The great men of the Jewish faith still have flaws. A serious study of the Jewish Bible would involve asking -- "what was going on with Isaac's marriage?" "Why did Jacob favor one son?" "Did David really sleep with a married woman, or was she technically divorced?"

So we speak critically of our own prophets!

Comment: The petition speaks explicitly about "blasphemy"! And not about something what is already there in the religions.

Comment: The word "blasphemy" does not appear in the petition.

Comment: @MonicaCellio FYI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blasphemy

Comment: @Maxood, so?  We were talking about the text of the petition.

Comment: @MonicaCellio You should be able to interpret that petition does talk about "balsphemy" of divine figures in major religions. *[Moderator-edited to remove insulting tone.]*

Comment: @Maxood The text of the petition is quite broad. All of Shalom's examples could easily fit within what it would ban. Therefore, I think that Shalom has demonstrated somewhat convincingly that this petition, at least, is not easily compatible with our tradition.

Comment: @IsaacMoses What is divine and an integral part of anyone's religion must be respected! According to our Islamic tradition, no Muslim can tolerate or resist mockery of Adam, Noah, Lot, Abraham, Yitzhaq, Yaakov, Yousef, Moses and all the prophets, saint and divine figures belonging or even not belonging to the children of Israel. I just cannot convince that why Judaism being a religion or tradition does not teach to respect other people's beliefs.

Comment: @IsaacMoses And what isprecisely broad in the petition's text?

Comment: @Maxood This is the entirety what the petition asks for: "To enact a law that prohibits any action or literature that offend prophets of major religions: - Moses - Jesus - Mohammad". "Offend" is a vague term that could easily include all kinds of speech, including the sorts of analyses that Shalom points out we have a strong tradition of. If you are interested in *learning* about what Judaism teaches regarding respecting or talking about other belief systems, I recommend, as Monica did in a comment on your question, that you post a question about that, rather than a stump for a petition.

Answer (score 3):

For a Jew it might be forbidden to insult a Rabbi, but we don't claim any right to tell non-Jews what to do. It isn't one of the seven Noahide laws that non-Jews are supposed to stick to.

Furthermore, we have faith in G-d that if someone has done something wrong, they will get punished for it. We don't need to get involved (other than an obligation to try to persuade a Jew to stop sinning, if there is a chance of success)

Comment: So are you implying that blasphemy and disrespecting the divine figures of other people's religions is allowed in Judaism?

Comment: @Maxood there is no specific prohibition, just as we don't expect them to respect ours

Comment: So basically mutual respect or interfaith hamrmony are not a part of Judaism  at all!!!!????

Comment: We have great respect for all _people_, as everyone is in the image of G-d. We do not respect _ideas_ that we consider incorrect.

Comment: The petition speaks about "prophets" and not "ideas"!

Comment: Believing in a certain prophet or another is an idea. Anyway, if you're confident you're right why don't you rely on the second half of my answer and leave it to G-d?

Comment: Again "beleif" is something else and you are free to believe whatever you like! What matters is expression and speech! I ask you: if someone call names to your mother or father, would you just leave that to G-d?

Comment: It would depend if anything good or constructive would come out of it. If not, then yes, I would have faith that G-d would take care of it. For those without such faith in the power of their prophets or gods, I can see why this might present a problem.

I don't think this is a constructive discussion. I've made my points, I will not be responding any more.

Comment: @limos "just as we don't expect them to respect ours": I do expect non-Jews to not needlessly make fun of our beliefs just as I expect Jews to not needlessly make fun of other's beliefs. I just don't think the US should outlaw it, just like it hasn't outlawed making fun of blacks or Hispanics.

Comment: @DoubleAA Of course it's true that society would function better and more cohesively if people respected each other's right to believe what they want. It's not a nice thing to do to make fun, and I don't think people should. But it's not a _religious_ requirement not to make fun of others' beliefs.

Comment: @@DoubleAA This is where the core difference comes in between Judaism and Islam. Judaism talk about mere "religious requirements" while Islam encompasses all spheres of life perosnal, demostic, social, communal, economical and even poltical. No society or community can exist with harmony and peace without "mutual respect" and this is what exactly Islam emphasizes upon!

Comment: @limos Absolutely it's a religious requirement to not make fun of anyone for no reason. Do you want to tell me that all discussions of good _middos_ and being a _mentch_ are not religious requirements? God wants us to be good religious human beings which certainly includes being a good human being.

Comment: @DoubleAA That was the first thing I said - that we have great respect for people. We have no obligation whatsoever to respect their beliefs.

Comment: @limos Not respecting their beliefs is not the same as disrespecting their beliefs. We can and should know they are wrong, but we shouldn't make fun of them for no reason.

Comment: @Maxood, I think you may be working under a misapprehension about the nature of religious duty in Judaism. If you're interested in learning more about this topic, I recommend that you start with at least the introduction to [this article](http://www.jewfaq.org/halakhah.htm).