# What is the penalty for someone who insults Judaism

Tags: reward-punishment

In a Jewish country where the law of Judaism is practised, if someone insults Judaism, makes fun of its prophets and defames Torah, what is the punishment for him (non Jew), if any?

Comment: Is he Jewish?  And what form does this defaming take -- just saying bad things about it, or working against it somehow (like preventing Jews from following its laws), or what?

Comment: @MonicaCellio his name is Muslim and he's in Pakistan according to his profile.

Comment: @PloniAlmoni the asker, sure, but I'm asking about the person he's asking about (the "someone" in "if someone insults...").

Comment: My guess is he's making a comparison, lhavdil, between sharia and halacha. I wish he'd clarify his question.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/21769

Comment: As far as I know there is only 1 jewish country, it's reasonably secular, so in general there is NO prohibition or penalty, at least not significant one, for "blasphemy". I would expect spitting on rabbi can get assault charge, but something like Ahok won't happen in Israel. http://www.thejakartapost.com/academia/2018/02/21/qa-what-you-need-to-know-about-ahoks-case-review-petition.html

Answer (score -4):

A non-Jew is supposed to follow the 7 laws of Bnai Noach, one of which is not to commit blasphemy; but I don't know precisely the definition of blasphemy used for non-Jews, for that one would have to consult a halachic (Jewish law) work on the subject or ask an Orthodox Rabbi who's studied this. As for a country where the law of the land is Jewish law, that probably won't happen until the Messiah comes and rules the world, as our prophets foretold. We are in a state of exile, even if we live in Israel, until that date.

The punishment for violating any of the 6 laws of Noach (adjudicated by a court established by non-Jews, the seventh law), incidentally, which are murder, theft, forbidden sexual relations, blasphemy, cruelty to animals, and idolatry, is the same. It's death. But Jews are not now supposed to impose our religion on others; as G-d decreed that due to our sins we are exiled and our Temple and rulership has been destroyed. Incidentally, as a non-Zionist, I don't believe we have the right to establish a state, secular or Jewish, in the state of Israel (almost all Zionists believe in a western secular state...) prior to the Messiah's arrival, but that's neither here nor there. Judaism is not a religion that believes that all others must now submit to it involuntarily.

Comment: -1. I mean, this is technically an answer, as it suggests that there may be a blasphemy prohibition at play and says what the punishment is if so. But it's not a good answer IMO, as it doesn't offer any argument supporting the blasphemy prohibition's being relevant.

Comment: What do you mean by "relevance"? I think he knows no earthly court exists that carries out the punishment.

Comment: I should add the questioner is a Muslim. Sharia has quite specific punishments for blasphemy.

Comment: By relevance I mean that the blasphemy prohibition includes a prohibition on the activities asked about above.

Comment: What activities are forbidden in the prohibition?

Comment: I don't know. Your answer implicitly proposes that the activities asked about above are, but offers no support for that proposition.

Comment: I said that I didn't know that clearly....

Comment: While it is certainly prohibited and bad to insult the Torah or defame a prophet, the specific Torah prohibition that is usually translated as "blasphemy" applies only to the extreme case of cursing God (Heaven forbid). See, for example, *Sefer HaChinuch* §70.